# Ruby on Rails - Settting up Reviews functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, associations, scaffolding

I am trying to set up a feature on my Ruby on Rails app that lets users to review pictures.

I've followed this guide as a reference.

http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyonrails/ss/blogpart4_4.htm

From my experiences working on other Ruby on Rails projects, I think a Posts/Comments relationship model can be used here for a Pictures/Reviews relationship.

I first generated a scaffold.

```
rails g scaffold review name:string body:text picture:references
```

I would like each picture page to have a separate page for its own reviews.

Since I don't need an Index Page for my reviews controller, I removed this line from my routes.rb file

```
resources: reviews
```

I replaced that by creating routes

```
match '/pictures/:id/reviews', to: 'reviews#show', via: 'get'
match '/pictures/:id/reviews/edit', to: 'reviews#edit', via: 'get'
match '/pictures/:id/reviews/new', to: 'reviews#new', via: 'get'
```

Here, my path involves nesting reviews inside pictures.

**Route**

```
favorite_picture_path   PUT     /pictures/:id/favorite(.:format)    pictures#favorite
pictures_path           GET     /pictures(.:format)                 pictures#index
                        POST    /pictures(.:format)                 pictures#create
new_picture_path        GET     /pictures/new(.:format)             pictures#new
edit_picture_path       GET     /pictures/:id/edit(.:format)        pictures#edit
picture_path            GET     /pictures/:id(.:format)             pictures#show
                        PATCH   /pictures/:id(.:format)             pictures#update
                        PUT     /pictures/:id(.:format)             pictures#update
                        DELETE  /pictures/:id(.:format)             pictures#destroy
users_path              GET     /users(.:format)                    users#index
                        POST    /users(.:format)                    users#create
new_user_path           GET     /users/new(.:format)                users#new
edit_user_path          GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)           users#edit
user_path               GET     /users/:id(.:format)                users#show
                        PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)                users#update
                        PUT     /users/:id(.:format)                users#update
                        DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)                users#destroy
sessions_path           POST    /sessions(.:format)                 sessions#create
new_session_path        GET     /sessions/new(.:format)             sessions#new
session_path            DELETE  /sessions/:id(.:format)             sessions#destroy
contacts_path           POST    /contacts(.:format)                 contacts#create
new_contact_path        GET     /contacts/new(.:format)             contacts#new
root_path               GET     /                                   pictures#welcome
users_new_path          GET     /users/new(.:format)                users#new
about_path              GET     /about(.:format)                    pictures#about
                        GET     /contacts(.:format)                 contacts#new
                        GET     /users/:id/favorites(.:format)      users#favorites
signup_path             GET     /signup(.:format)                   users#new
signin_path             GET     /signin(.:format)                   sessions#new
signout_path            DELETE  /signout(.:format)                  sessions#destroy
                        GET     /pictures/:id/reviews(.:format)     reviews#show
                        GET     /pictures/:id/reviews/edit(.:format)    reviews#edit
                        GET     /pictures/:id/reviews/new(.:format) reviews#new
updated_path            GET     /updated(.:format)              pictures#newest_updates
                        GET     /top-rated(.:format)            pictures#high_ratings
```

**ReviewsController**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def edit
     @picture = Picture.find(params[:picture_id])
     @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:picture_id])
    @review = @picture.reviews.build(params[:review])

    if @review.save
      ;flash[:notice] = 'Review was successfully created.'
      redirect_to @picture
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error creating review: #{@review.errors}"
      redirect_to @picture
    end
  end

  def update
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:picture_id])
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])

    if @review.update_attributes(params[:review])
      flash[:notice] = "Review updated"
      redirect_to @picture
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error updating your review"
      redirect_to @picture
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:picture_id])
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.destroy
    redirect_to(@review.post)
  end

  private

    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:username, :body, :picture_id)
    end
end
```

I deleted the index action from my ReviewsController.

**Models**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end
```

Above, I established a one-to-many relationship between pictures and reviews.

**Reviews Migration**

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.text :body
      t.references :picture, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Based on my understanding on Rails, this should work.

**Pictures#Show Page**

```
<% @title = "#{@picture.title}" %>

<h4 class = 'indent'>Picture Statistics</h4>

  <ul id = 'view'>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> <%= @picture.title %></li>
    <li><strong>Category:</strong> <%= @picture.category %></li>
    <li><strong>Rating:</strong> <%= pluralize(@picture.rating, 'Star') %></li>
    <li><strong>Favorited:</strong> By <%= pluralize(@picture.users.count, 'User') %></li></br>
  </ul>

  <% if @picture.rating > 4 %>

  <button class = 'top-picture'>Top Rated</button>

  <% end %>

<%= form_for @picture do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :stars, 'Rating', class: 'indent' %>
    <div class= "rating">
      1 &#9734;<%= f.radio_button :stars, '1' %>
      2 &#9734;<%= f.radio_button :stars, '2' %>
      3 &#9734;<%= f.radio_button :stars, '3' %>
      4 &#9734;<%= f.radio_button :stars, '4' %>
      5 &#9734;<%= f.radio_button :stars, '5' %>
    </div>
  </p>

  <p class = 'indent'>
   <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Review">
  </p>

  <a href = "/pictures/:id/reviews">Reviews</a>

<% end %>
<p class = 'indent'>
  <a class="btn btn-info" href="/pictures" role="button">Index</a>
</p>
```

However, when I click on a link in my Pictures/:id(show page)

```
<a href = "/pictures/:id/reviews">Reviews</a>
```

**RecordNotFound Error**

```
Active Record::RecordNotFound in ReviewsController#show
Couldn't find Review with id=:id

Extracted source (around line #54):
53 def set_review
54  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
55 end
56
57 def review_params
```

Since I encountered a RecordNotFound error, I suspect the problem lies in the ReviewsController, most likely with the params.

I believe that I have the right idea, but I made a mistake somewhere. Feedback and criticism are greatly appreciated. Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, I'm just not very good in Ruby.

Comment: Where are you seeing this link? `<a href = "/pictures/:id/reviews">Reviews</a>` . Can you share view code?

Comment: View code for my pictures#show action or for my reviews#show action?

Comment: Share any example URL with value of `:id`

Comment: Because of url being formed with :id in it, the params[:id] is resulting in :id. If you put the value of id in the url like `pictures/10/reviews` it should work.

Comment: It sounds like `<a href = "/pictures/:id/reviews">Reviews</a>` literally has ":id" in it.  You need an actual id number there instead.  Are you using the URL helpers?

Comment: You might wanna fix the following syntax error: ;flash[:notice] = 'Review was successfully created.'

Comment: @railsdev I copied and pasted that from the webstie and just changed posts to pictures and comments to reviews. Do I not need the semicolon?

Comment: It should be flash[:notice] be sure to read code you're using or else you won't learn anything... Or retype it by hand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Routes**

For the sake of posterity, you'll be best setting your routes up as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pictures do
   resources :reviews, only: [:show, :edit, :new]
end
```

Whenever you create routes in Rails, you need to remember the entire framework has been built around ["objects" / "resources"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). That's why the routes are known as `resourceful` routes (and why they have the `resources` directive) - they allow you to define the routes *around* the different resources of your application

I've recommend using a [`nested` resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) structure.

--

**Helpers**

Your problem was resolved using the code provided by `Santosh` and the like. IE:

```
<%= link_to "Your Link", your_link_path(@object) %>
```

You need to appreciate *how* this works. Each time you use a `route` helper in Rails (in the `link_to` helper), it will look through your routes & find the details it needs.

You were referencing the following path: `pictures/:id/reviews` - as discovered, this is wrong because Rails does not have any bearing on the URL of a link besides building it at render time.

Considering Rails is a [stateless HTTP-based framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), Rails has to collate any data upon each request. This means if you want to build links, you have to let Rails build the link at render, passing a static set of data through to your controller in the back-end

Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Great answer, I assume I should remove the three 'match' routes because nested resources probably does the exact same thing right?

Answer (score 2):

```
match '/pictures/:id/reviews', to: 'reviews#show', via: 'get'
match '/pictures/:id/reviews/edit', to: 'reviews#edit', via: 'get'
```

These 2 routes do not have a review id, but your controller action expects them. make this change

```
match '/pictures/:picture_id/reviews/:id', to: 'reviews#show', via: 'get'
match '/pictures/:picture_id/reviews/:id/edit', to: 'reviews#edit', via: 'get'
```

And change this

```
<a href = "/pictures/:id/reviews">Reviews</a>
```

to

```
<a href = "/pictures/#{@picture.id}/reviews/#{@review.id}">Reviews</a>
```

But you should seriously consider using [Resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) and [helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: I see! I was passing in a symbol inside the path, when I should have passed an embedded variable. Thank you, I will try this out.

Answer (score 2):

As you have `.html.erb` file, try to avoid writing raw HTML.

Just update this link:

```
<a href = "/pictures/:id/reviews">Reviews</a>
```

To

```
<%= link_to "Reviews", picture_reviews_path(@picture) %>
```

**Edit:**

You should assign names to your `match` statements like:

```
match '/pictures/:id/reviews', to: 'reviews#show', via: 'get', :as => 'picture_reviews'
```

It will generate:

```
picture_reviews GET    /pictures/:id/reviews(.:format)          reviews#show
```

Comment: link_to arguments are reversed

Comment: Only problem with using the ruby helpers is that my routes do not have a helper for my reviews actions, so I think I have to use html. No routes match picture_reviews_path when I run rake routes.

Comment: paste your `rake routes`. You may add it in post

Comment: I added my routes to my post

Comment: so you should add names your urls. Have a look on updated ans

Comment: Alright, I think I'm getting somewhere now. Now, it says it can't find a review with id = 3. Is that because I need to create them?

Comment: yeah you must have `review` with `id` 3, before displaying it

Answer (score 1):

Consider using nested resources rather than building them out manually

```
resources :pictures, except: [:index] do
  resources :reviews
end
```

And as others mentioned, you should use the rails link_to to generate proper URLs

Comment: my apologies, I meant that I don't need an index page for the reviews, but I have them for my pictures. But is it possible to change that code to put except: [:index] on resources :reviews instead and remove it from resources :pictures?

Comment: :except can be used as an option on any resources in the routes file. Moving it to the reviews should do what you are looking for